# Find the number of days using date picker and current date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am Trying to get the difference between the number of days. using date picker dialog with the current date

```
datepicker = findViewById(R.id.date_picker_date);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                String date = day + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year;


                TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(date);

                datepicker.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                datepicker.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);


                // date picker dialog
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                            {
                                datepicker.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                            }
                        }, year, month, day);
                picker.show();
```

Not getting the difference between the picking date and current date

Answer (score 1):

Use this method, pass your date in the format "MM/dd/yyyy" and you will get the difference between two dates in days.

```
public static String daysDiff(String cDate, String rDate){
        String dayDifference;
        try {
            //Dates to compare
            String CurrentDate = cDate;
            String FinalDate = rDate;

            Date date1;
            Date date2;

            SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            //Setting dates
            date1 = dates.parse(CurrentDate);
            date2 = dates.parse(FinalDate);

            //Comparing dates
            long difference = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
            long differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            //Convert long to String
            dayDifference = Long.toString(differenceDates);

//            Log.e("hit", "HERE: " + dayDifference);

            return dayDifference;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
//            Log.e("DIDN'T WORK", "exception " + exception);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code and it works fine for me. Works for lower versions as well. Try this

```
public static DateBean getDateDifferenceInDDMMYYYY(Date from, Date to)
{
    Calendar fromDate=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar toDate=Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDate.setTime(from);
    toDate.setTime(to);
    int increment = 0;
    int year,month,day;

    System.out.println(fromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    if (fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
    {
        increment =fromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    System.out.println("increment"+increment);

    // DAY CALCULATION
    if (increment != 0) {
        day = (toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + increment) - fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        increment = 1;
    } else {
        day = toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    // MONTH CALCULATION
    if ((fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment) > toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        month = (toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 12) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment);
        increment = 1;
    } else {
        month = (toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment);
        increment = 0;
    }

    // YEAR CALCULATION
    year = toDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + increment);

    DateBean dateDifference = new DateBean(""+year, ""+month, ""+day);

    System.out.println(year+"\tYears\t\t"+month+"\tMonths\t\t"+day+"Days");
    return dateDifference;
}
```

and your DateBean as below

```
public class DateBean
{
    String year, months, days;

    public DateBean(String year, String months, String days)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.months = months;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getMonths() {
        return months;
    }

    public void setMonths(String months) {
        this.months = months;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```